# How to keep children divs from growing bigger than their parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to add text to a child div, but never have it get bigger than its parent, but rather get scrollbars on the child.  Currently I have:

```
<div id="chatwindow">
  <div class="dragtitle">This is a title</div>
  <div id="chatcontainer">
    <div id='helplog'></div>
    <div id='msgline'><textarea rows="2"></textarea></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the entire page with the css at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwj75L0e/).  click on the 'add line' button a few times and you will see the problem.

What happens is as text is added to the `#helplog` div, eventually it pushes everything past the border of the `#chatwindow` div.  So you get: [image: after adding lots of line].

Notice that the text, e.g., line 7 and 8, and the msgbox (which is outlined in red) have moved out of the black borders which surround their parent, `#chatwindow`.

I have tried adding wrappers with `position:absolute`, but either this collapses the entire box or it has no effect.  The goal if for the `#chatwindow` div to remain the same size and for the text in `#helplog` to scroll.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What do you want to happen when more text is added? Have the parent box grow, have the new content hidden, or have a scrollbar appear?

Comment: Have a scrollbar appear

Comment: You need to define a height on the helplog div

Comment: But I always want the helplog to fill the space between the `#dragtitle` and the `#msgline` and I want `#msgline` to be at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to scroll instead of overflow you can add `overflow-y: scroll` as a CSS property to `#chatwindow`. This will cause it to become a scrollable area when it gets too big.

```css
#foo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But then the ENTIRE `#chatwindow` div will have a scrollbar.  I only want the `#helplog` div to scroll.